# How to filter data inside an ng-repeate using the ng-repeat value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I need to filter some data according to the value I get from ng-repeate.
my html looks like this.
I need to display the data from other scope object(`$scope.allData`) by filtering using the value

```
<div ng-repeat="value in selectedIds">
    <h6>Id</h6>{{}} <br/>
    <h6>Name</h6>{{}} <br/>
    <h6>Age</h6>{{}} <br/>

   </div>
```

and my controller look like

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.selectedIds=[{id:"123"},{id:"124"},{id:"125"},{id:"126"}];
  $scope.allData=[{id:"123",name:"James",age:"21"},
  {id:"124",name:"James",age:"21"},
  {id:"125",name:"Frank",age:"22"},
  {id:"126",name:"John",age:"24"},
  {id:"127",name:"Jimmy",age:"26"},
  {id:"128",name:"Ann",age:"61"},
  {id:"129",name:"Mark",age:"41"},
  {id:"130",name:"Lach",age:"33"}
  ];
});
```

[I create the the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tPkrdpny2wdZdg66kTXk?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `filter` in your ng-repeat function.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="value in selectedIds">
      <div ng-repeat="values in allData | filter: value.id">
         <h6>Id</h6>{{values.id}} <br/>
         <h6>Name</h6>{{values.name}} <br/>
         <h6>Age</h6>{{values.age}} <br/>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Hope it works in your case. here is the working [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/5lSpipiJH1FcvspUh4Zo?p=preview)